# Python: Opening a unicode named xls file from the script

Tags: python, windows, unicode, subprocess, os.system

How do you open a **unicode** named file (with **spaces**) from within a **Python** script under **Windows**?
filename for example: `Hello עולם.xls`

For a non-unicode non-spaced xls file, `os.system(filename)` works well.
For a non-unicode     spaced xls file, `os.system('"'+filename+'"')` works well.

But for a unicode spaces xls file...

both `os.system(filename)` and `subprocess.call(new_filename)` give:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't encode characters in position
>   12-13: ordinal not in range(128)

`os.system(new_filename.encode('UTF-8'))` gives:

> 'Hello' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

and `subprocess.call(new_filename.encode('UTF-8'))` gives:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`os.startfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile), not `os.system()`. You probably also want to use [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) e.g.

```
import os
import sys
os.startfile(filename.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()))
```

Answer (score 6):

`os.startfile()` as mentioned by Bradley (+1), but make sure to pass a Unicode string in, and not a byte string.

Windows NT filenames are natively Unicode, and Python on Windows has (unlike most other scripting languages) specific support built in for passing Unicode-strings into APIs that expect filenames:

```
os.startfile(u'Hello \u05e2\u05d5\u05dc\u05dd.xls')  # u'Hello עולם.xls'
```

If you pass in a byte string it will go instead to the standard C `stdio` library, which on the Microsoft C Runtime will map byte strings to Unicode filenames using the machine's default character set (aka ANSI code page), which is what `getfilesystemencoding()` is returning. That'll still work if every character in the filename is representable in the ANSI code page, but the example filename would fail for anything but a Hebrew installation of Windows.

Unfortunately the same Unicode support isn't available for `system()` or `subprocess`. But you probably don't need to use the command line in this case.

Comment: You're knowledge on this topic is impressive.